# Printing Datagridview data in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

i'm struggling on how to solve my problem with print preview with my datagridview. this is the whole code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class FrmPrintClassSchedule

Dim strConn As String = "Data Source=Jansen;Initial Catalog=SLCBRegistrarDB;Integrated Security=True"
Dim sqlCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConn)
Dim CMD As SqlCommand
Dim Adapter As SqlDataAdapter
Dim Reader As SqlDataReader
Dim DT As DataTable

Private Sub LoadCLASSSCHEDULES()
    sqlCon = New SqlConnection("Data Source=Jansen;Initial Catalog=SLCBRegistrarDB;Integrated Security=True")
    sqlCon.Open()
    CMD = sqlCon.CreateCommand
    CMD.CommandText = ("SELECT [Class Schedule LINE].SchedID, ListofSubjects.[Course No.], ListofSubjects.[Descriptive Title],Curriculum.[Lab.]+ Curriculum.[Lec.] , UtlyTIMETable.[FROM Time]+'-'+ UtlyTIMETable.[TO Time]+'  '+ UtlyDAY.Day+'  '+ UtlyRoom.Building+' '+UtlyRoom.[Room No.], UtlyInstructor.[Last Name]+', '+ UtlyInstructor.[First Name], YearLevel.[Year Level], CourseOfferings.Course, CourseOfferings.[Degree Course], ListCurricularYear.[Curriculum Year], [Class Schedule Status].[Class Schedule Status] " &
                        "FROM  [Class Schedule LINE] INNER JOIN Curriculum ON [Class Schedule LINE].[Subject Code] = Curriculum.[Subject Code] INNER JOIN CourseOfferings ON Curriculum.CourseID = CourseOfferings.CourseID INNER JOIN ListofSubjects ON Curriculum.SubjectID = ListofSubjects.SubjectID INNER JOIN Section ON [Class Schedule LINE].Section = Section.SectionID INNER JOIN UtlyDAY ON [Class Schedule LINE].DayID = UtlyDAY.DayID INNER JOIN UtlyInstructor ON [Class Schedule LINE].InstructorID = UtlyInstructor.IntructorID INNER JOIN UtlyRoom ON [Class Schedule LINE].RoomID = UtlyRoom.RoomID INNER JOIN UtlyTIMETable ON [Class Schedule LINE].TimeID = UtlyTIMETable.TimeID INNER JOIN YearLevel ON Curriculum.YearLevelID = YearLevel.[Year Level] INNER JOIN ListCurricularYear ON Curriculum.CurriculumID = ListCurricularYear.CurriculumID INNER JOIN [Class Schedule Status] ON [Class Schedule LINE].StatusofSchedule = [Class Schedule Status].StatusofClassScheduleID " &
                        "WHERE (Section.Section = '" & cmbSection.Text & "') AND (YearLevel.[Year Level] = '" & txtYearLevel.Text & "') AND (CourseOfferings.Course = '" & cmbCOURSE.Text & "') AND (CourseOfferings.[Degree Course] = '" & cmbDegreeTitle.Text & "') AND (ListCurricularYear.[Curriculum Year] = '" & cmbCurricularyear.Text & "') AND ([Class Schedule Status].[Class Schedule Status] = 'Active')")
    Reader = CMD.ExecuteReader()
    If Reader.HasRows Then
        Dim DT As New DataTable
        DT.Load(Reader)
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.DataSource = DT

        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(6).Visible = False
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(7).Visible = False
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(8).Visible = False
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(9).Visible = False
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(10).Visible = False

        dgvPrintClassSchedule.RowHeadersWidth = 25
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(0).Width = 75
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Schedule No."
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Units"
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(4).HeaderText = "Schedule and Room Assignment"
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(5).HeaderText = "Instructor"
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(1).Width = 100
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(3).Width = 50
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(2).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(4).Width = 200
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(5).Width = 150
        dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Calibri", 9)

    End If
    Reader.Close()
    sqlCon.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadCURRICULUM()
    Try
        sqlCon.Open()
        Dim QUERY As String
        QUERY = "SELECT * FROM ListCurricularYear"
        CMD = New SqlCommand(QUERY, sqlCon)
        Reader = CMD.ExecuteReader
        While Reader.Read
            cmbCurricularyear.Items.Add(Reader.GetString(1))
        End While
        sqlCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub LoadCOURSES()
    Try
        sqlCon.Open()
        Dim QUERY As String
        QUERY = "SELECT Course, [Degree Course] FROM CourseOfferings"
        CMD = New SqlCommand(QUERY, sqlCon)
        Reader = CMD.ExecuteReader
        While Reader.Read
            cmbCOURSE.Items.Add(Reader.GetString(0))
            cmbDegreeTitle.Items.Add(Reader.GetString(1))
        End While
        sqlCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub cmbCOURSE_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbCOURSE.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        sqlCon.Open()
        Dim QUERY As String
        QUERY = "SELECT * FROM CourseOfferings WHERE Course='" & cmbCOURSE.Text & "'"
        CMD = New SqlCommand(QUERY, sqlCon)
        Reader = CMD.ExecuteReader
        While Reader.Read
            cmbDegreeTitle.Text = Reader.GetString(2)
        End While
        sqlCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub cmbSection_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbSection.SelectedIndexChanged
    LoadCLASSSCHEDULES()
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' structire to hold printed page details
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Structure pageDetails
    Dim columns As Integer
    Dim rows As Integer
    Dim startCol As Integer
    Dim startRow As Integer
End Structure
''' <summary>
''' dictionary to hold printed page details, with index key
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private pages As Dictionary(Of Integer, pageDetails)

Dim maxPagesWide As Integer
Dim maxPagesTall As Integer

''' <summary>
''' this just loads some text values into the dgv
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sender"></param>
''' <param name="e"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Sub FrmPrintClassSchedule_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'LoadCLASSSCHEDULES()
    LoadCURRICULUM()
    LoadCOURSES()



    'dgvPrintClassSchedule.RowHeadersWidth = CInt(dgvPrintClassSchedule.RowHeadersWidth * 1.35)
    'For r As Integer = 1 To 100
    'Dim y As Integer = r
    'Dim fmt As String = "R{0}C{1}"
    'dgvPrintClassSchedule.Rows.Add()
    'dgvPrintClassSchedule.Rows(r - 1).SetValues(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(Function(x) String.Format(fmt, y, x)).ToArray)
    'dgvPrintClassSchedule.Rows(r - 1).HeaderCell.Value = r.ToString
    'Next
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' shows a PrintPreviewDialog
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sender"></param>
''' <param name="e"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Sub btnPreview_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrintPreview.Click
    Dim ppd As New PrintPreviewDialog
    ppd.Document = PrintDocument1
    ppd.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    ppd.ShowDialog()
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' starts print job
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sender"></param>
''' <param name="e"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    PrintDocument1.Print()
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' the majority of this Sub is calculating printed page ranges
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sender"></param>
''' <param name="e"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Sub PrintDocument1_BeginPrint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.BeginPrint
    ''this removes the printed page margins
    PrintDocument1.OriginAtMargins = True
    PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Drawing.Printing.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)

    pages = New Dictionary(Of Integer, pageDetails)

    Dim maxWidth As Integer = CInt(PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width) - 40
    Dim maxHeight As Integer = CInt(PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height) - 40 + Label1.Height

    Dim pageCounter As Integer = 0
    pages.Add(pageCounter, New pageDetails)

    Dim columnCounter As Integer = 0

    Dim columnSum As Integer = dgvPrintClassSchedule.RowHeadersWidth

    For c As Integer = 0 To dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns.Count - 1
        If columnSum + dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(c).Width < maxWidth Then
            columnSum += dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(c).Width
            columnCounter += 1
        Else
            pages(pageCounter) = New pageDetails With {.columns = columnCounter, .rows = 0, .startCol = pages(pageCounter).startCol}
            columnSum = dgvPrintClassSchedule.RowHeadersWidth + dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(c).Width
            columnCounter = 1
            pageCounter += 1
            pages.Add(pageCounter, New pageDetails With {.startCol = c})
        End If
        If c = dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns.Count - 1 Then
            If pages(pageCounter).columns = 0 Then
                pages(pageCounter) = New pageDetails With {.columns = columnCounter, .rows = 0, .startCol = pages(pageCounter).startCol}
            End If
        End If
    Next

    maxPagesWide = pages.Keys.Max + 1

    pageCounter = 0

    Dim rowCounter As Integer = 0

    Dim rowSum As Integer = dgvPrintClassSchedule.ColumnHeadersHeight

    For r As Integer = 0 To dgvPrintClassSchedule.Rows.Count - 2
        If rowSum + dgvPrintClassSchedule.Rows(r).Height < maxHeight Then
            rowSum += dgvPrintClassSchedule.Rows(r).Height
            rowCounter += 1
        Else
            pages(pageCounter) = New pageDetails With {.columns = pages(pageCounter).columns, .rows = rowCounter, .startCol = pages(pageCounter).startCol, .startRow = pages(pageCounter).startRow}
            For x As Integer = 1 To maxPagesWide - 1
                pages(pageCounter + x) = New pageDetails With {.columns = pages(pageCounter + x).columns, .rows = rowCounter, .startCol = pages(pageCounter + x).startCol, .startRow = pages(pageCounter).startRow}
            Next

            pageCounter += maxPagesWide
            For x As Integer = 0 To maxPagesWide - 1
                pages.Add(pageCounter + x, New pageDetails With {.columns = pages(x).columns, .rows = 0, .startCol = pages(x).startCol, .startRow = r})
            Next

            rowSum = dgvPrintClassSchedule.ColumnHeadersHeight + dgvPrintClassSchedule.Rows(r).Height
            rowCounter = 1
        End If
        If r = dgvPrintClassSchedule.Rows.Count - 2 Then
            For x As Integer = 0 To maxPagesWide - 1
                If pages(pageCounter + x).rows = 0 Then
                    pages(pageCounter + x) = New pageDetails With {.columns = pages(pageCounter + x).columns, .rows = rowCounter, .startCol = pages(pageCounter + x).startCol, .startRow = pages(pageCounter + x).startRow}
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

    maxPagesTall = pages.Count \ maxPagesWide

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' this is the actual printing routine.
''' using the pagedetails i calculated earlier, it prints a title,
''' + as much of the datagridview as will fit on 1 page, then moves to the next page.
''' this is setup to be dynamic. try resizing the dgv columns or rows
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sender"></param>
''' <param name="e"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim rect As New Rectangle(20, 20, CInt(PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width), Label1.Height)
    Dim sf As New StringFormat
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center

    e.Graphics.DrawString(Label1.Text, Label1.Font, Brushes.Black, rect, sf)

    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near

    Dim startX As Integer = 50
    Dim startY As Integer = rect.Bottom

    Static startPage As Integer = 0

    For p As Integer = startPage To pages.Count - 1
        Dim cell As New Rectangle(startX, startY, dgvPrintClassSchedule.RowHeadersWidth, dgvPrintClassSchedule.ColumnHeadersHeight)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlLight), cell)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, cell)

        startY += dgvPrintClassSchedule.ColumnHeadersHeight

        For r As Integer = pages(p).startRow To pages(p).startRow + pages(p).rows - 1
            cell = New Rectangle(startX, startY, dgvPrintClassSchedule.RowHeadersWidth, dgvPrintClassSchedule.Rows(r).Height)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlLight), cell)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, cell)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvPrintClassSchedule.Rows(r).HeaderCell.Value.ToString, dgvPrintClassSchedule.Font, Brushes.Black, cell, sf)
            startY += dgvPrintClassSchedule.Rows(r).Height
        Next

        startX += cell.Width
        startY = rect.Bottom

        For c As Integer = pages(p).startCol To pages(p).startCol + pages(p).columns - 1
            cell = New Rectangle(startX, startY, dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(c).Width, dgvPrintClassSchedule.ColumnHeadersHeight)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlLight), cell)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, cell)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(c).HeaderCell.Value.ToString, dgvPrintClassSchedule.Font, Brushes.Black, cell, sf)
            startX += dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(c).Width
        Next

        startY = rect.Bottom + dgvPrintClassSchedule.ColumnHeadersHeight

        For r As Integer = pages(p).startRow To pages(p).startRow + pages(p).rows - 1
            startX = 50 + dgvPrintClassSchedule.RowHeadersWidth
            For c As Integer = pages(p).startCol To pages(p).startCol + pages(p).columns - 1
                cell = New Rectangle(startX, startY, dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(c).Width, dgvPrintClassSchedule.Rows(r).Height)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, cell)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvPrintClassSchedule(c, r).Value.ToString, dgvPrintClassSchedule.Font, Brushes.Black, cell, sf)
                startX += dgvPrintClassSchedule.Columns(c).Width
            Next
            startY += dgvPrintClassSchedule.Rows(r).Height
        Next

        If p <> pages.Count - 1 Then
            startPage = p + 1
            e.HasMorePages = True
            Return
        Else
            startPage = 0
        End If

    Next

End Sub

End Class
```

After data are loaded in the datagridview, then when i click print preview button, it should be working but this error always comes out:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Error Code:

e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvPrintClassSchedule.Rows(r).HeaderCell.Value.ToString, dgvPrintClassSchedule.Font, Brushes.Black, cell, sf)

I can't find a way on how to get rid of this error.. please help..Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  We do not need your whole code, just enough to demonstrate the error and the context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that dgvPrintClassSchedule.Rows(r).HeaderCell is not null before using the value.

try e.Graphics.DrawString("Test", dgvPrintClassSchedule.Font, Brushes.Black, cell, sf)

Do you still see the exception?

Is dgvPrintClassSchedule.Font defined?

Comment: ow yes! thanks man..that is what i'm talking about.. oh sorry for the late feedback. it was already 11:30 PM when i was able to posted my question. any way thanks a lot..

Comment: Is their any way were i will print specific columns only in the datagridview using the code i provided above?